# CF Distribution status (edge servers)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way for me to use AWS cli/api to verify that my static file(s) reached the edge servers once iv'e updated my s3 origin?

Flow im imagining:
Updating s3 origin -> waiting for CF to report OK that my update reached all CF edge servers -> continue with my CI operations.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with other cloud providers, you don’t push your content to Cloudfront, you will instead place the CDN in front of your resources and have them cached as they are retrieved on a per-file basis. You can control the TTL of the cache by setting the right Cache-Control headers. If you want the cache to be flushed and files be re-retrieved from the origin before the TTL expires, you can [invalidate the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html). This will clear the CDN cache, and Cloudfront will look up the resources on the origin again for a given URL.